# How to test janus video conference on localhost

Tags: browser, localhost, webrtc, janus, janus-gateway

I am new to Janus,
installed Janus on localhost, running demo video conference successfully, I am using IP address(**http://192.168.29.241/janus/videoroomtest.html**) to access video conference, but when I tried to open this IP in multiple laptops which are connected to each other through wifi, I am not able to get others users stream when all are in the conference.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe WebRTC requires an SSL connection. You will probably need to enable SSL/TLS in the Janus configuration files and get a certificate from somewhere like Let’s Encrypt. I personally have this functionality working through SSL/https.